# Why am I getting 'NameError: uninitialized constant Pry' when gem is installed properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pry

I have installed `pry` version 0.10.4 on my application and I have delegated my task in my rake file to run `Pry` when I need to debug and check my code.

```
task :console do
    Pry.start
end
```

But every time I type in `rake console` I get the error below:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Pry
/Users/kenkuts/Desktop/Projects/flatiron_school/sinatra-restful-routes-lab-cb-000/Rakefile:9:in block in <top (required)>'
/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in <top (required)>'
/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
/Users/kenkuts/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => console
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `require 'pry'` at the start of your rakefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rake tasks don't automatically load the gems - any that you use have to be explicitly required.

In your case, you can simply add the following:

```
require 'pry'

task :console do
  Pry.start
end
```

You could also use the [`pry-rails`](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) gem, which will handle launching the Rails console with pry.

Two other quick tips:

- in the Rails console, you can quickly switch to Pry with the eponymous `pry` command
- there's a good (but old) read about incorporating Pry here: http://lucapette.me/pry-everywhere

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.